# Errors while creating a new project with WSL2, Docker and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am having these errors when trying to create a new project with Docker using the command:

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/project | bash
```

It seems like everything is going well until the end when it throws these errors:

```
  - Installing spatie/ignition (1.4.5): Extracting archive
  - Installing spatie/laravel-ignition (2.0.0): Extracting archive
    Install of fakerphp/faker failed
    Install of nesbot/carbon failed
    Install of monolog/monolog failed
    Install of league/commonmark failed
    Install of laravel/serializable-closure failed
    Install of laravel/framework failed
    Install of laravel/sail failed
    Install of laravel/sanctum failed

In Filesystem.php line 314:
Could not delete /opt/try/vendor/composer/3f779ba1/briannesbitt-Carbon-4967
  128/src/Carbon/Lang:


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [<package> [<directory> [<version>]]]

bash: line 19: ./vendor/bin/sail: No such file or directory
bash: line 20: ./vendor/bin/sail: No such file or directory

sudo apt-get update` to see if it get fixed, but no.
```

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the very same issue on WSL2 with Ubuntu, after a while the installs start failing - always at the same point, the same installs.

It is not a memory or network issue, it is related to the filesystem - not sure what is going on though.

That is because building from within the Linux filesystem, e.g. `/home/foo` just works, but if you are on the Windows filesystem e.g. `/mnt/c` it does not.

You may try with Composer 1 or 2 (not sure what you are using in the example).

Otherwise, just build in the Linux fs and `cp -R`, `mv` or `rsync` the contents into your Windows fs path.